# Sound not working at all in Skype

Tags: sound, xubuntu, skype

I can't get sound to work at all in Skype (version 4.2.0.11). Video works fine, but when I try a test call it just says "Problem with audio playback". I'm running Xubuntu 13.04. There are many many options in the settings for sound (image attached) - have tried all of them and none work. Any suggestions gratefully received!

[image: Skype sound options]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I chose HD-audio generic... and it started to work.

plinovodja

Comment: Tried that, alas still no joy... might reinstall OS (especially as 13.10 is out now), see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this will sound stupid, but first few times I tried to change configuration I didn't notice " Apply" button in the bottom...